# When click icons Raised Button size changed. How to fix this?

Tags: dart, flutter

when clicking the loalization icons raised Button sized change. How to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: please share code

Answer (score 0):

The size of your `RaisedButton` is depending on the text that you are setting in it, you need to give your `RaisedButton` a fixed size, or wrap it with an `Expanded` to fill the available space it can fill. Hope it helps!